# Any Idea Why My C Code Can't Read from /proc?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have been able to write a program that can read any text files... except the ones found in /proc. Any file that I try to read from /proc shows up empty.

But whenever I type

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

on terminal, I am presented with my CPU info.

I can also see the file when I open it with a text editor, such as gedit or leafpad.

So it seems that /proc files are indeed text files, but my C program is having a hard time reading them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char* readFileString( char* loc ) {
        char *fileDat;
        FILE * pFile;
        long lsize;

        pFile = fopen( loc, "r" );

        // Grab the file size.
        fseek(pFile, 0L, SEEK_END);
        lsize = ftell( pFile );
        fseek(pFile, 0L, SEEK_SET);

        fileDat = calloc( lsize + 1, sizeof(char) );

        fread( fileDat, 1, lsize, pFile );

        return fileDat;
}

int main( void ) {
        char *cpuInfo;

        cpuInfo = readFileString( "/proc/cpuinfo" );

        printf( "%s\n", cpuInfo );

        return 0;
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The files from `/proc` have a size of 0 byte because they are generated on the fly by the kernel.

See here for more information on proc filesystem:

http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html

Comment: Another errant user bitten by not using the correct file-reading loop.

Comment: The user was burned not by an incorrect file-reading loop, but by failing to check for errors.

Comment: Normally if you want to load the whole file, it makes sense to allocate the right amount of memory first to avoid expensive reallocs. /proc is just broken in this sense. If the files in /proc aren't going to behave as normal files but as pipes, they should show up as fifos or some other special file type detectable by stat, rather than breaking ordinary file semantics...

Answer (score 9):

Most `/proc/` textual files are intended to be read sequentially by a classical loop like

```
FILE *f = fopen("/proc/cpuinfo", "r");
size_t sz = 0;
char * lin = 0;
do {
   ssize_t lsz = getline (&lin, &sz, f);
   if (lsz<0) break;
   handle_line_of_size (lin, lsz);
} while (!feof (f));
fclose (f);
```

seeking don't work on them. A bit like for pipes.

Comment: It's bad practice to use feof() in the while argument. See this: http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#4.2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the size of a file, stat(2) is the way to go.  But for what you're doing, either allocate a very large buffer (RAM is cheap and this is a one-shot program) you fread() into after you fopen() it, or learn about realloc(3) and use that in your file-reading loop.  As ouah said, the files in /proc are special.

For general-purpose use, and especially for strings, calloc() is a waste of cpu cycles, as setting the 0th char of the returned allocation area to '\0' is sufficient to make it an empty string, regardless of the data following that first byte.

Comment: But AFAIK `stat(2)`  dont work for most `/proc/` textual file. You have to `read(2)` till EOF.

Comment: "As @ouah said, the files in /proc are special." (And therefore won't work in some ways.)  Using a normal file-reading loop as you suggested below is the right way to read them.