# Open file without extension

Tags: c, linux, unix, ubuntu

I need to open a file without extension in /proc/ folder using fopen() sys call, unfortunately it doesn't work.

This is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *f;
    int size;

    //open /proc/meminfo
    f = fopen("/proc/meminfo", "r");
    printf("errno after open: %s\n", strerror(errno)); //errno = Success

    //create buffer
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(f);
    printf("size: %d\n", size);
    char buffer[size];
    bzero(buffer,size);
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);

    //fill the buffer and print
    fread(buffer,sizeof(char),size,f);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that size is = 0, and errno is "Success", so, the file is not read even if it has been opened.

Do you have some ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check `f` the result of the file open. The file must have the exact file name and exist as a full path name or on an available path.

Comment: Are you sure that's your program? The include file should be `#include <string.h>`. When corrected, I get the output `errno after open: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Of course, i've just written the above program to try. Fixing with string header I've the same results.

The result of fopen() is a pointer, I've checked.

EDIT: I think that isn't a path name problem, trying with /boot/memtest86+.bin it works, the only difference is the extension in the end of the path name

Comment: Well perhaps that file (without extension) really does exist and its size is 0. Presumably you do check that `f!=NULL`, essential after all file open operations?

Comment: `ls -la /proc/meminfo` ?

Comment: I've just checked that the real size of the file is zero bytes. Maybe should I use finer grane than byte grane? :/

Comment: I don't think you can have a 1-bit file size.

Comment: Of course you can't...

Comment: Of course...too bad! I think the problem is the grain, a byte is too large for my purpose!

Comment: So I guess it's the time for another question, where you describe your purpose (in case you need help)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992430/any-idea-why-my-c-code-cant-read-from-proc).

Comment: Thanks at all for your help! Sorry if my question is a duplicate, I've looked with other keywords :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some (most?) files in `/proc` have 0 size because their content is dynamically generated on read. So, read to EOF as a normal file to get the content. This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *f;
    int c;

    f = fopen("/proc/meminfo", "r");

    if (!f) {
        return -1;
    }

    while ( (c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c",c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The extension of the file doesn't matter at all.

You have several issues in your code:
 1. You are not testing the return value of `fopen`. From the manpages:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> Upon  successful  completion  fopen(),  fdopen()  and  freopen() return a FILE
>   pointer.  Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.

2. The allocation of your buffer is wrong

You cannot allocate an array of char with a variable. So you have to change:

```
char buffer[size];
```

by either:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 512
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

or dynamically

```
char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
if (buffer == NULL)
  return 1;
```

(of course you can improve this snippet). Also don't forget to `free` buffer in the end.

3. Not really an error, but you don't need to fill the buffer with the whole file. You can just read the file "lines by lines", or at least, per bytes (for instance `BUFFER_SIZE`) and just store what you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your #2 has been overcome in more modern versions of C.

Comment: All good catches, but it won't fix his problem. The root cause is that you can't obtain size of file in `/proc`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8992465/3866447).

Comment: Indeed @SamProtsenko, so #3 should be used :)

Comment: Really thanks! Victor solution is working, I had not thought at his solution! ;) Thanks for the other hints!